# request has no content-length

Tags: python, request

it seems every now and then i get a bad response, i see that in the header content-legth:0 but it seems i only get the content-length in the header wen it is a bad response, shoudn't i always get the content-length in a response?
here is my code

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint
import time 

def read_OSRS_GE(item_id):
    api_url="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/catalogue/detail.json?item="
    # get all items and put em in file
    # print(api_url+str(item_id))
    r=requests.get(api_url+str(item_id))
    print(r)
    header=r.headers
    print(header)
    data=r.json()
    # print("dataid",data["item"]["id"])
    # pprint(data)
    row=[]
    row.append(int(time.time()))
    row.append(data["item"]["id"])
    row.append(data["item"]["name"])
    row.append(data["item"]["current"]["price"])
    row.append(data["item"]["members"])
    print(row)
    return
def get_items():
    api_url="https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json"
    #get all items and put em in file
    # print(api_url)
    r=requests.get(api_url)
    data=r.json()
    # pprint(data)
    counter=1
    for key, value in data.items():
        print("item id:",key)
        print("call:",counter)
        read_OSRS_GE(key)

        counter+=1

    return
get_items()
```

Comment: `Content-Length` zero or absent means the response size is unknown. The way you handle this is by simply assuming everything that comes next is part of the response until the connection is closed. In those cases, the server usually presents the header `Connection: close` (instead of `Connection: keep-alive`) which reinforces the intended behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the size of the raw response in bytes from `len(r.content)`

The response may not necessarily have the `Content-Length` header set.

The response from the example you provided currently contains a `Transfer-Encoding` field. The data is sent in a series of chunks, so the `Content-Length` header is emitted.

[MDN: Transfer-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#Directives)